# Sums of Linq values in select

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, model, sum

So I have always came across this situation when using linq. Say I have code like below:

```
            var results = _context.Products.Select(d =>
            new Models.ProductData()
            {
                Id = d.ProductId,
                Name = d.Product.Name,
                Qty = d.Number.Where(y => y.Active && y.CodeId == 5 && y.Status == "NEW").Sum(y => y.FeeAmount),
                Qty1= d.Number.Where(y => y.Active && y.CodeId == 7 && y.Status == "NEW").Sum(y => y.Fee),
                Total = d.Number.Where(y => y.Active && y.CodeId == 5 && y.Status == "NEW").Sum(y => y.FeeAmount) + d.Number.Where(y => y.Active && y.CodeId == 7 && y.Status == "NEW").Sum(y => y.Fee)
            }
            );
```

For the total value, is there a better way to calculate the total without having to write out all the linq statements with + symbols in between? It would be a lot nicer to be able to write something like

```
Total = Qty + Qty1
```

I could omit the total from the initial mapping and the remap it grouping by Id and assigning the totals there by referencing Total = Qty + Qty1 but that just seems to round about.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why not have `Total` a read only property with a getter that returns `Qty + Qty1` ? In that case you don't need to set it in the first place

Comment: Since `Total` is a calculated value it would be bad design to let it remember its own value, what if you change `Qty1` later, you would then also have to update `Total`. What do you do if `Qty` + `Qty1` != `Total`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `Models.ProductData` class, define the `Total` property as follows:

```
public double Total {
    get {
        return this.Qty + this.Qty1;
    }
}
```

and avoid to set it in the Linq query.

Comment: Well now I feel silly for not thinking of this! Thanks for the answer. I will mark it in 6 mins.

Comment: Bro, you don't have to be ashamed, we are all here to learn and share knowledge